# How to drag image to specific circle area in andEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am beginner to AndEngine. I wanted to drag a  .png image to specific circle or square. If it isn't dragged to the correct position then the image should return to staring position.I have implemented up to the  drag and drop part.

Comment: look into sprite.collidesWith(anotherSprite) function

Comment: Try using colidesWith(IShape shape). You can check in an if else condition. In case shape is not the target, just return  your sprite to initial position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this work:

1. Set a `onTouchListener` to the movable sprite.
2. On `Action_down`, capture the original position of the movable sprite (*old X & Y*).
3. On `Action_move`, update the movable sprite position as the current touch position (*current X & Y*).
4. Say, set the center of another object (i.e. square) as *target X & Y*.
5. On `Action_up`, compare the movable sprite *current X & Y* with that of the *target X & Y*.
6. If sprite X & Y are close to your target sprite coordinates (say, +/- 5 pixels or else), then set the target X & Y as the movable sprite coordinates. Otherwise, restore the old X & Y to the movable sprite.

One of the moving cards Andengine example may greatly help on your moving sprite coding, you can try to search it out.